# Enabling the macro-paradise Scala compiler plugin in Maven projects

Tags: scala, maven, scala-2.10, scala-macros, scala-maven-plugin

I have the ordinary scala-2.10 macros working in a maven project just by including the scala-reflect.jar library as a dependency in the pom, but what do I need to turn on macro-paradise? I am using scala-2.10 and scala-maven-plugin-3.1.5.

Comment: Updated the docs: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like I got it to work with the following additions to the pom.xml

```
 <repositories>
   ...
   <repository>
     <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
      <name>sonatype sapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
   ...
  </repositories>
```

and

```
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      ... scala-maven-plugin identification...
      <configuration>
        ...
        <compilerPlugins>
          <compilerPlugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>macro-paradise_2.10.2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </compilerPlugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
        ...
      </configuration>
      ...
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
```

Comment: Is there something like CrossVersion.full in Maven?

Answer (score 2):

for me although with the above relative clear description, I still can't figure out where this should be placed. and then this link helped: [example config](https://github.com/mikolak-net/bomba/blob/master/pom.xml)

and I always had trouble fill in the correct groupId and arti-fact Id for this. as it disagrees in the above and [scala-lang ref](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html), until I opened `oss` repo and figured out the listed config there.